# Is there a way to show all static pages (aka pages) in Blogger

Tags: scripting, blogger, posts

I need to modify a template for Blogger in a way to put all the static pages I wrote inside a dropdown menu.
Is there a way to do this? I really can't figure out using Blogger syntax. I can only loop through page posts, not pages and anyway not **all** the posts; only the posts in the page the user is.

This is the code I tried to use:

```
<b:section class='main' id='main1' name='Main' showaddelement='yes'>
  <b:widget id='Blog2' locked='false' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'>

    <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
      <b:include name='allposts'/>
    </b:includable>

    <b:includable id='allposts'> 
      <b:loop values='data:posts' var='thisPost'>
        <li>
          <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
              <a href='#'><data:thisPost.title/></a>
          </b:if>
        </li>
      </b:loop>
    </b:includable>
  </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display all pages only in Page List Widget.

```
<b:widget id='PageList1' title='Pages' type='PageList'>
  <b:includable id='main'>
    <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
      <a expr:href='data:link.href'>
        <data:link.title/>
      </a>
    </b:loop>
  </b:includable>
</b:widget>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is useful, but applying this solution it shows only "home page". Do I have to change the section tag or anything else?

Comment: No, just open section "Layout" and go to Pages Gadget settings. You must check all pages to show (http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-pNH9wJLsrHs/VmmcgBxHk4I/AAAAAAAAXXY/vLaB0_WdYoo/s1600/Screenshot%2B2015-12-10%2Bat%2B07.30.41%2B-%2BEdited%2B%25281%2529.png).